# C- adding names of items in knapsack problem

Tags: arrays, c, string, knapsack-problem

I tried to solve the knapsack problem in C language, and the algorithm itself was successful, but I want to print out the names of items **in the knapsack**(not all the items in input). Please help me.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))

int DP[103][100003];
int w[103]; //weight of items
int v[103]; //value

int main() {
    char s1[11][11]; //saved names of all items here

    int n, k; //n = number of items, k = size of knapsack
    printf("input number of items and size of knapsack");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k); 

    printf("\n input name, weight, value of items");
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        scanf("%s %d %d", s1[i-1], & w[i], &v[i]);

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { //knapsack algorithm
        for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
            if (j >= w[i])
            {
                DP[i][j] = MAX(DP[i - 1][j], DP[i - 1][j - w[i]] + v[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                DP[i][j] = DP[i - 1][j];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n maximun value: %d)",DP[n][k]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I want to print out the names of items in the knapsack. Please help me."_ . If you have a need to output the names, then you can call `printf(...)`, probably best within the inner `for(...)` loop, and using the `s1` variable that you populated in the `scanf(...)` function above . Have you tried this yet?

Answer (score 0):

> *"...but I want to print out the names of items in the knapsack."*

Since you have already scanned in the names, the most common way output them would be to place `printf(...)` statements in your `for(...)` loop, eg:

```
if (j >= w[i])
{
    DP[i][j] = MAX(DP[i][j], DP[i][j - w[i]] + v[i]);
    printf("Name: %s Weight %d Value: %d\n", s1[i], w[i], v[i]);
}
```

Some other items:

```
int DP[103][100003];
```

a 10 megabyte array could cause problems if you do not have a large stack-size defined.  There may be more efficient ways to do this if you size your arrays at run-time according to user input.

Note also that in C, indexing begins at zero  Typically then your `scanf` and loops would be change as follows:

FROM:

```
    scanf("%s %d %d", s1[i-1], & w[i], &v[i]);

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { //knapsack algorithm
    for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
```

TO:

```
    i = 0;
    scanf("%s %d %d", s1[i], & w[i], &v[i]);

for (int i; i < n; i++) { //knapsack algorithm
    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
```

Also it is always a good idea to initialize all variables:

```
int DP[103][100003] = {{0}};
int w[103] ={0}; //weight of items
int v[103] = {0}; //value
//etc.
```

Note on using `scanf(...)`:  It is always recommended that you verify the items intended to be parsed from `stdin` (or whatever source you are using) are actually parsed before assuming wrongly and attempting to use them if they did not parse correctly. Something like this will do that:

```
if(scanf("%d %d", &n, &k) 1= 2)
{
    printf("Error in count of arguments parsed.  Exiting");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that there are logic errors in your code that I have not addressed.  For example testing equality of an index value against a user provided weight does not make sense:

```
 if (j >= w[i])
```

I suggest that you [use the features of a good debugger](https://u.osu.edu/cstutorials/2018/09/28/how-to-debug-c-program-using-gdb-in-6-simple-steps/) to help you finish verifying that the code actually does what you intended it to.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and edits, but isn't        if (j >= w[i])
{
    DP[i][j] = MAX(DP[i][j], DP[i][j - w[i]] + v[i]);
    printf("Name: %s Weight %d Value: %d\n", s1[i], w[i], v[i]);
}       just printing all the items that I've included? I want to get a solution about printing just the items those are in the knapsack

Comment: @HCyan  Make adjustments as you see fit.  Move calls to printf out of the loops, and into `if(...)` clause to include only the values that match the criteria you want.

Comment: Aside - subtracting  the value of weight from the value of an index seems like an odd _difference_ measurement to me.  (`DP[i][j - w[i]]`)